# Can't send data with $http.post in Ionic Framework

Tags: http, post, asp.net-web-api, ionic-framework

I'm trying make an application with Ionic framework which can take and send data to MS SQL server. For this I am using web api. I have no problem with taking data but something wrong with send new datas. Here is my ionic code :

```
angular.module('starter.controllers',[])

.controller('CheckListCtrl', function($scope, ChecklistService, $ionicPopup) {
  function addCheck(){
    ChecklistService.addCheck()
  }

.factory('ChecklistService', ['$http', function ($scope, $http) {
  var urlBase = 'http://localhost:56401/api';
  var CityService = {};
  CityService.addCheck = function(){
    var url = urlBase + "/TBLCHECKLISTs"
    var checkdata = {
      AKTIF : true,
      SIL : false,
      KAYITTARIHI : Date.now(),
      KULLANICIID : 3,
      BASLIK : "Onur",
      TAMAMLANDI : false,
      TAMAMLANMATARIHI : null,
      GUN : 1
    }
    var request = $http({
      method: 'POST',
      url: url,
      headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'},
      data: checkdata
    });
    return request;
  }
  return CityService;
}]);
```

And here is my web api:

```
        [HttpPost]
        [ResponseType(typeof(TBLCHECKLIST))]
        public IHttpActionResult PostTBLCHECKLIST(TBLCHECKLIST tBLCHECKLIST)
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return BadRequest(ModelState);
            }

            tBLCHECKLIST.KAYITTARIHI = DateTime.Now;
            db.TBLCHECKLISTs.Add(tBLCHECKLIST);
            db.SaveChanges();

            return CreatedAtRoute("DefaultApi", new { id = tBLCHECKLIST.TABLEID }, tBLCHECKLIST);
        }
```

When i try to send i get this exception:

[image]

After, I realize that I take that exception because my checkdata is never come to web api. I don't know why.

These are not the datas I send:

[image]

I have tried different versions of post request but nothing. When I try to send data with PostMan, it works and I can insert data to my database. But why I can't do it with my application? Can anybody help me?

Comment: I dont know about .net but are you allowing cross domain headers in your api

Comment: Yes I am allowing cross domain headers

Answer (score 0):

I think this should be the problem:

```
headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
```

Try this:

```
return $http.post(url, checkdata);
```

And in your API:

```
[HttpPost]
[ResponseType(typeof(TBLCHECKLIST))]
public IHttpActionResult PostTBLCHECKLIST([FromBody]TBLCHECKLIST tBLCHECKLIST)
{
    //code here
}
```

Also, make sure your `checkdata` properties match the ones in your `TBLCHECKLIST` c# type.

Comment: Now I am getting XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:50367/api/TBLCHECKLISTs. Response for preflight has invalid HTTP status code 405

Comment: Try then setting instead of application/x-www-form-urlencoded to application/json. Also, make sure you allow the method Options in your web api.